# Ajax connected webparts in sharepoint 2013

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, web-parts

I need to implement custom treeview with categories and connect this webpart with ListView webpart. Can this be done with ajax? How? And how to pass param from provider via JS (I know only __doPostBack method, are there any other ways)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to look at the JavaScript API for SharePoint:
[API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193034.aspx)

And then integrate code that queries your views in a list with the jsTree jQuery plugin:
[jsTree Reference](https://www.jstree.com/)

Now you can use JQuery to determine what's happening with your list view web part, but it will be time consuming.  I would use the Microsoft Javascript API to create a drop down of the various views you have in your list, and then render that data in such a way it will work with the markup jsTree requires.